# How to inject javascript code to iframe head using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to inject javascript code into an `iframe` head using `jquery` using the following code.

```
 var snippets_js='<?php echo $snippets_javascript;?>';
 var scriptjs   = document.createElement("script");
 scriptjs.type  = "text/javascript";
 scriptjs.text  = snippets_js;
 $('#iframehtml').contents().find('head').append(scriptjs);
```

Error I am getting is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

below image showing the error on line

[image]

Comment: I am trying to minify the javascript but no success

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add the code as text in your question, then it's much easier for others to help you. Here you find a guid [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you'll get more answers perhaps if you read and follow it for further questions ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code to the following format:

```
var snippets_js= 'script_line1' +
    'script_line2' +
    'script_line3' +
    'script_line4';
```

Edit 2:

According to your post, just remove two `'` before and after your codes:

```
var snippets_js=<?php echo $snippets_javascript;?>
```

Comment: snippets_js getting dynamic data from database... how its possible?

Comment: the main page and the iframe content should be same origin.